# Postgres UUID and hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that has a UUID column (It's not primary key). I'm using Postgres and hibernate. The type I have for this column is https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html .

If I do

```
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, updatable = false)
private UUID myUuid;
```

Everything works just fine. But, I don't want this column to be a UUID and I want it to be a Java String just for the sake of it. When I change to

```
@Type(type = "pg-uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, updatable = false)
private String myUuid;
```

I get

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
```

When I do

```
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, updatable = false)
private String myUuid;
```

I get

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "uuid" is of type uuid 
but expression is of type character varying
```

When I do

```
@Convert(converter = UUIDAttributeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
private String uuid;
```

where UUIDAttributeConverter is:

```
@Converter
public class UUIDAttributeConverter implements  
AttributeConverter<String, PGobject> {
  @Override
  public PGobject convertToDatabaseColumn(String uuid) {
    PGobject toInsertUUID = new PGobject();
    toInsertUUID.setType("uuid");
    try {
        toInsertUUID.setValue(UUID.fromString(uuid).toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return toInsertUUID;
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToEntityAttribute(PGobject dbData) {
    return dbData.toString();
  }
}
```

I get

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
```

Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

When I do the converter again but this time where converter is

```
@Converter
public class UUIDAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, 
String> {
  @Override
  public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
    return UUID.fromString(s);
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID id) {
    return id.toString();
  }
}
```

I get

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "uuid" is of type uuid but expression is 
of type bytea
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

What am I missing here? I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118210/understanding-hibernate-type-annotation So I would say `@Type` and `@Convert`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate

Comment: @RC. Type can convert cannot be used together. We will have AnnotationException: AttributeConverter and explicit Type cannot be applied to same attribute. 

I don't have the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495233/postgresql-uuid-supported-by-hibernate . For me if I try to use Java UUID, it's all ok. But not the same if my uuid is a java string. Cheers